# Nodejs and express, the router file is loaded, but the router is not working

Tags: node.js, express, router

I am using the Node.js as the backend server for mobile application, but some how the Router of express is not working. None of the router work. I copied the code from my previous project, and code of my previous project does not work either.

Node version: 12.10.0
Express version: 4.17.1

I really do not know where I did it wrong, I appreciate your help.

Thanks!!!

Here is my APIs:
The apis are in the config file

```
    api: {
        client: {
            prefix: "./api/user",
            url: [
                "/login",
                "/register",
                "/logout",
                "/search",
                "/address",
                "/cart",
                "/purchasedHistory",
                "/products",
                "/staticImg"
            ]
        },
        admin: {
            prefix: "./api/admin",
            url: [
                "/main"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Here is how I register router

```
// route to display versions
app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    res.json(config.api);
});
// REGISTER THE PREFIXES
for (var k in config.api) {
    config.api[k].url.forEach(aUrl => {
        app.use(aUrl, require(config.api[k].prefix + aUrl));        
    });
}
```

Here is the login.js

```
const router = express.Router();

// logs all the api requests
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // TODO log the request here
    if (config.debug) console.log('login: someone has made a request');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

router.get('/get', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hahahahahahah' });   
});
//Return the router for the server
module.exports = router;
```

When I use the api

```
http://localhost:8080/api/
```

I got the following result

```
{"client":
    {"prefix":"./api/user","url":["/login"]},
"admin":
   {"prefix":"./api/admin","url":["/main"]}
}
```

But when I run a api

```
http://localhost:8080/api/login/get
```

I got this error

```
Cannot GET /api/login/get
```

This is the output of express in debug mode

```
  express:router dispatching GET /api/login/get +1m
  express:router query  : /api/login/get +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /api/login/get +0ms
  express:router corsMiddleware  : /api/login/get +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /api/login/get +0ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /api/login/get +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/login/get +0ms
  express:router haltOnTimedout  : /api/login/get +0ms
```

The output of express look normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express `app.use` used to register middlewares on all requests or you can register middlewares on a specific path/route then the middleware will execute on specified path.

Here you are using `app.use('/login')` instead of `app.use('/api/login')`. If you hit `http://localhost:8080/login/get` it will work but `http://localhost:8080` won't work.